# Order data by pivot table when try to use With

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have tables `Polfzms <- Genes`

`Polfzm` model have next relation

```
public function gene()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Gene');
}
```

I need get all data from `Polfzms` table with data from `Genes` table and order it by `name` from pivot table (`Genes`). I try next

```
$data = Polfzm::with([
    'gene' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('name', 'asc');
    },
])->get();
```

but it not order data by name. How can I do it?

Comment: 1. you're using a `belongsTo` relationship, which does not use pivots (`belongsToMany` does) 2. do you expect the `Polfzm` to be ordered or the related `gene`? Your current method would order just the `gene`

Comment: `with` is eager loading it and which actually generates two separate sql. check the generated sql to verify.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set this in the relationship definition:

**Polfzm.php**

```
public function gene()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Gene')->orderBy('name', 'asc');
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
$data = Polfzm::with('gene')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could use a collection `sortBy` helper for this one.

An example could be:

```
$data = Polfzm::with('gene')
    ->get()
    ->sortBy(function ($polfzm) {
        return $polfzm->gene->name;
    });
```